# How to use another int in a different class file java

Tags: java, int

Hello i'm trying to make a game for my final project on school.  What i'm trying to do is have two files in one package using the same integers.

File one is setting the values

```
public class Scores {

int wins = 0;

int losses = 0;

int ties = 0;

    }
```

then in my second file i'm using them

```
     public void Stats(int wins) {

    String win1 = String.valueOf(wins);

    winOutput.setText("You have" + win1 + ".");

}
```

i'm still new to java and I can't seem to get this working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you post both classes ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to call a method `getvalue` its easier to write just

```
System.out.println("you have " + win1);
```

and it should run.

Comment: Or 'winOutput("youhave "+win1)'

Comment: In my game I have a window that opens up and shows your scores in text fields.

Comment: Ok but to create a new string you do not have to call the method valueOf from the int. You can just "add" ste integer to the string e. g. NewString = "you have "+win1

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Java is object-oriented. The file `Scores.java` is not going to set any scores without being instantiated. You need to pass an instance of `Scores` (the `Scores` object) that you have created and used to the `Stats(int)` method.